# JQuery Parent→Child selector doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, selector

```
var $track = $('>.jScrollPaneTrack', $container);
```

Works in jquery 1.4.2, doesn't work in jquery 1.7.2.

By 'works' I mean returning jQuery object to be able to do this, for example:

```
alert($track.html());
```

and

```
$track[0].css(..., ...);
```

etc

---

I think I found a solution:
Instead of using the variable the usual way - track - it now wants from me to use it like that - $(track)

For example:

was:

```
track[0].css(..., ...);
```

now:

```
$(track[0]).css(..., ...);
```

Due to some new internal optimisation, when jquery returns dom-objects instead of usual jquery ones.

Answer (score 3):

That selector should work in 1.7.2, however [is being depreciated](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) in a future version of jQuery. Try doing it with `.children`

```
$track = $container.children('.jScrollPaneTrack')
```

Comment: I have tried using 'children', it won't work :( Doesn't even give me .html() contents of it. I'm trying to make this plugin http://code.google.com/p/droplist/ working with the latest jquery v.1.7.2 instead of the old 1.4.2 one, because it gives exceptions with the latest jquery.

Comment: It's a pretty handy plugin btw, totally worth reanimating: http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/wutgJbulyNxUmyDaFvs-bQ?feat=directlink

Comment: I made a quick run-through of the code and updated a few compatibility issues, here it is untested: http://pastebin.com/sYXWF4Su

Comment: I think i found the solution - take a look at the first post.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method instead:

```
var $track = $container.children('.jScrollPaneTrack');
```

The jQuery [docs for the child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) state:

> The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future
>   release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative
>   selectors.

However, it hasn't been deprecated yet, so it should still work for you.